# Wordpress filter tag by category (grab category from uri)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I know there are many question about how to filter tags by category, but I need some help.

```php
$args = array(
    'tag' => get_queried_object()->slug, 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'interior',
        ),
    )
); 
//get all posts
$posts_new = get_posts($args);
```

It work, but I would like to grab the category from the URL when it's like `example.com/tag/lexington/?category=interior` or `example.com/tag/lexington/category/interior`, to use it in the `terms` parameter from the above query.

Thanks for your attention.

---

In the last hours I've tries to do this in my `functions.php`:

```php
function category_tag_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%tag_category%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^tag/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&tag_category=$matches[2]');
}
add_action('init', 'category_tag_rewrite_rule');
```

Now it's sending me to the tag page (`tag.php` template), but `get_query_var('tag_category')` returns me nothing from this template.

Something may be wrong with my regexp.

Comment: How are you getting it from URL?

Comment: see in comment below. sorry